# Como meter un order by en una tabla

Tags: php, html5, mysqli, php7

Necesito ordenar los datos de una tabla, 
en la base de datos los muestra ordenadamente osea 1 2 3...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero en mi aplicación web me muestra los datos en desorden osea 1 3 2. no encuentro la razón de esto como puedo meter un oder by en la tabla o como puedo solucionar esto gracias ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  <?php
    include "../config/config.php";//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos

    $action = (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] !=NULL)?$_REQUEST['action']:'';
    if (isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id_del=intval($_GET['id']);
        $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from project where id='".$id_del."'ORDER BY id DESC");
        $count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
            if ($delete1=mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM project WHERE id='".$id_del."' ")){
            ?>

    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <strong>Aviso!</strong> Datos eliminados exitosamente.
    </div>
    <?php 
        }else{
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <strong>Error!</strong> Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.
    </div>
    <?php
        } //end else
    } //end if
?>
        <?php
    if($action == 'ajax'){
        // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
         $q = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_REQUEST['q'], ENT_QUOTES)));
         $aColumns = array('name');//Columnas de busqueda
         $sTable = "project";
         $sWhere = "";
        if ( $_GET['q'] != "" )
        {
            $sWhere = "WHERE (";
            for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
            {
                $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".$q."%' OR ";
            }
            $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
            $sWhere .= ')';
        }
        $sWhere.=" order by name desc";
        include 'pagination.php'; //include pagination file
        //pagination variables
        $page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page']))?$_REQUEST['page']:1;
        $per_page = 10; //how much records you want to show
        $adjacents  = 4; //gap between pages after number of adjacents
        $offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
        //Count the total number of row in your table*/
        $count_query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $sTable  $sWhere");
        $row= mysqli_fetch_array($count_query);
        $numrows = $row['numrows'];
        $total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
        $reload = './projects.php';
        //main query to fetch the data
        $sql="SELECT * FROM  $sTable $sWhere LIMIT $offset,$per_page";
        $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        //loop through fetched data
        if ($numrows>0){

            ?>
            <table  class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action order-column ">
                <thead>
                    <tr  class="headings">
                        <th  class="column-title">Nombre</th>
                         <th  class="column-title">Codigo </th>
                          <th class="column-title">tipo </th>
                           <th class="column-title">prioridad</th>
                            <th class="column-title">estado</th>
                             <th class="column-title">responsable</th>
                              <th class="column-title">nivel</th>
                               <th class="column-title">apoyo</th>
                                <th class="column-title">Quien Apoya</th>  
                                 <th class="column-title">Area</th> 
                                  <th class="column-title">Programa</th>   
                                   <th class="column-title">Estimado</th> 
                                    <th class="column-title">Archivo</th>
                                     <th class="column-title">Creacion</th>
                                      <th class="column-title">Planeacion</th>
                                       <th class="column-title">Cierre</th>
                                        <th class="column-title">entrega</th>
                                         <th class="column-title">Fecha real</th>
                                          <th class="column-title">Nota</th>
                                           <th class="column-title no-link last"><span class="nobr"></span></th>
                                            </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php 
                        while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                            $id=$r['id'];
                             $name=$r['name'];
                              $Codigo=$r['Codigo'];
                               $tipo=$r['tipo'];
                                $prioridad=$r['prioridad'];
                                 $estado=$r['estado'];
                                  $responsable=$r['responsable'];
                                   $nivel=$r['nivel'];
                                    $apoyo=$r['apoyo'];
                                     $ayudante=$r['ayudante'];
                                      $area=$r['area'];
                                       $programa=$r['programa'];
                                        $estimado=$r['estimado'];
                                         $archivo=$r['archivo'];
                                          $fecha=date("d/m/Y", strtotime($r['fecha']));
                                           $planeacion=date("d/m/Y", strtotime($r['planeacion']));
                                            $cierre=date("d/m/Y", strtotime($r['cierre']));
                                             $entrega=date("d/m/Y", strtotime($r['entrega']));
                                              $reall=date("d/m/Y", strtotime($r['reall']));
                                               $description=$r['description'];
                ?>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id;?>" id="id<?php echo $id;?>">
                     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $name;?>" id="name<?php echo $id;?>">
                      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $Codigo;?>" id="Codigo<?php echo $id;?>">
                       <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $tipo;?>" id="tipo<?php echo $id;?>">
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $prioridad;?>" id="prioridad<?php echo $id;?>">
                         <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $estado;?>" id="estado<?php echo $id;?>">
                          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $responsable;?>" id="responsable<?php echo $id;?>">
                           <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $nivel;?>" id="nivel<?php echo $id;?>">
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $apoyo;?>" id="apoyo<?php echo $id;?>">
                             <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ayudante;?>" id="ayudante<?php echo $id;?>">
                              <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $area;?>" id="area<?php echo $id;?>">
                               <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $programa;?>" id="programa<?php echo $id;?>">
                                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $estimado;?>" id="estimado<?php echo $id;?>">
                                 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $archivo;?>" id="archivo<?php echo $id;?>">
                                  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $fecha;?>" id="fecha<?php echo $id;?>">
                                   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $planeacion;?>" id="planeacion<?php echo $id;?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $cierre;?>" id="cierre<?php echo $id;?>">
                                     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $entrega;?>" id="entrega<?php echo $id;?>">
                                      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $reall;?>" id="reall<?php echo $id;?>">
                                       <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $description;?>" id="description<?php echo $id;?>">


                        <tr class="even pointer">
                         <td  ><?php echo $name;?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $Codigo;?></td>
                           <td><?php echo $tipo;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $prioridad;?></td>
                             <td ><?php echo $estado;?></td>
                              <td ><?php echo $responsable;?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $nivel;?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $apoyo;?></td>
                                 <td><?php echo $ayudante;?></td>
                                  <td><?php echo $area;?></td>
                                   <td><?php echo $programa;?></td>
                                    <td ><?php echo $estimado;?></td>
                                     <td ><?php echo $archivo;?></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $fecha;?></td>
                                       <td><?php echo $planeacion;?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $cierre;?></td>
                                         <td><?php echo $entrega;?></td>
                                          <td><?php echo $reall;?></td>
                                           <td ><?php echo $description;?></td>
                                            <td colspan=20><span class="pull-right">
                                             <a href="#" class='btn btn-default' title='Editar Tarea' onclick="obtener_datos('<?php echo $id;?>');" data-toggle="modal" 
                                              data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg-udp"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a> 
                                               <a href="#" class='btn btn-default' title='Borrar Tarea' onclick="eliminar('<?php echo $id; ?>')"><i class="glyphicon 
                                                glyphicon-trash"></i> </a>
                                                 <a title="Agregar actividad" class="btn btn-default " data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg-add"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
                                                 </span>
                                                  </td>
                                                   </tr>
                    <?php
                    } //end while
                ?>
                  <tr>
                   <td colspan=20><span class="pull-right">
                    <?php echo paginate($reload, $page, $total_pages, $adjacents);?>
                     </span>
                      </td>
                       </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            <?php
        }else{
           ?>
                <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <strong>Aviso!</strong> No hay datos para mostrar
                </div>
                <?php    
                 }
                  }
                   ?>
```

Comment: Y tú variable $query dónde está? Tienes que ponerle un ORDER BY id DESC

Comment: podrias agregar tu $query, para darte una mejor respuesta

Comment: Ya esta en el código se me olvido lo siento ya lo pueden ver

Comment: Sólo tienes que poner el orden en la consulta: `"SELECT * from project where id='".$id_del."' ORDER BY id"`

Comment: Muchas Gracias pero no me funciona ya lo había intentado sigue igual :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos tan solo deberias agregar el **ORDER BY** a tu query :

```
$query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from project where id='".$id_del."' ORDER BY id ASC ");
```

Ahora bien el orden es dado como lo desees ASC(ascendente) y DESC(descendente), espero esto solucione tu problema.

Para mayor detalle te sugiero revisar la documentación: [ORDER BY MYSQL](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/order_by.php)

Comment: Muchas Gracias pero ya lo había intentado y no me funciona :(

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar ORDER BY id DESC

```
 $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from project where id='".$id_del."' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Comment: Amigo no me funciona  ya he intentado varias veces :(

Comment: Intenta quitando el "where id=' ".$id_del." ' " tal vez sea eso?